# Two variables have different sample sizes. In this case, what method of differential analysis should I choose?

Tags: r, spss, anova

I have two variables:`Treatment`and`Variety`.Both of them have different sample size. `Treatment`has two samples with the size of 30 and 29. `Variety` has six samples with the size of 10, 10, 10, 10, 9 and 10. Since Two-way ANOVA requires that the sample sizes of different groups of variables must be the same, it doesn't work for my data.

In my case, what method of differential analysis should I choose?

Here is the original data:

```
df<-structure(list(Treatment = c("Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", 
                                 "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Irrigated", 
                                 "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Non-irrigated", 
                                 "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", 
                                 "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", 
                                 "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", 
                                 "Non-irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", 
                                 "Irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", 
                                 "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", 
                                 "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", 
                                 "Non-irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", 
                                 "Irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", 
                                 "Non-irrigated", "Non-irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", 
                                 "Irrigated", "Irrigated"), Variety = c("MG 000 - Sultana", "MG 000 - Sultana", 
                                                                        "MG 000 - Sultana", "MG 000 - Sultana", "MG 000 - Sultana", "MG 000 - Sultana", 
                                                                        "MG 000 - Sultana", "MG 000 - Sultana", "MG 000 - Sultana", "MG 000 - Sultana", 
                                                                        "MG I - ES Pallador", "MG I - ES Pallador", "MG I - ES Pallador", 
                                                                        "MG I - ES Pallador", "MG I - ES Pallador", "MG I - ES Pallador", 
                                                                        "MG I - ES Pallador", "MG I - ES Pallador", "MG I - ES Pallador", 
                                                                        "MG I - ES Pallador", "MG I - Isidor", "MG I - Isidor", "MG I - Isidor", 
                                                                        "MG I - Isidor", "MG I - Isidor", "MG I - Isidor", "MG I - Isidor", 
                                                                        "MG I - Isidor", "MG I - Isidor", "MG I - Isidor", "MG I/II - Santana", 
                                                                        "MG I/II - Santana", "MG I/II - Santana", "MG I/II - Santana", 
                                                                        "MG I/II - Santana", "MG I/II - Santana", "MG I/II - Santana", 
                                                                        "MG I/II - Santana", "MG I/II - Santana", "MG I/II - Santana", 
                                                                        "MG II - Blancas", "MG II - Blancas", "MG II - Blancas", "MG II - Blancas", 
                                                                        "MG II - Blancas", "MG II - Blancas", "MG II - Blancas", "MG II - Blancas", 
                                                                        "MG II - Blancas", "MG II - Ecudor", "MG II - Ecudor", "MG II - Ecudor", 
                                                                        "MG II - Ecudor", "MG II - Ecudor", "MG II - Ecudor", "MG II - Ecudor", 
                                                                        "MG II - Ecudor", "MG II - Ecudor", "MG II - Ecudor"), SLA = c(6.11979828701114, 
                                                                                                                                       10.6254856510255, 73.8218290951699, 29.0006487652397, 37.6144729444593, 
                                                                                                                                       83.6870982783873, 81.6922624733632, 91.7471974108231, 78.2428634817335, 
                                                                                                                                       91.5116772823779, 29.168895183201, 61.5906086966241, 14.65223598377, 
                                                                                                                                       34.7719920728235, 32.1653415260809, 103.550713082565, 118.558911914481, 
                                                                                                                                       116.11947891962, 109.557820588374, 111.893715659634, 52.3916990809266, 
                                                                                                                                       119.551533801741, 57.7048307642606, 79.1967868761258, 117.00190159895, 
                                                                                                                                       114.301353187694, 117.425877519045, 109.794693805518, 107.864889144166, 
                                                                                                                                       93.3961947857212, 50.9822201038779, 87.0884448470195, 72.3995564890519, 
                                                                                                                                       91.4470642048975, 40.1212526443246, 128.791243850548, 118.563349962414, 
                                                                                                                                       106.80279354539, 126.674734818823, 121.888643915629, 95.0494513291909, 
                                                                                                                                       10.8570381219191, 14.8565013632106, 34.5660188629493, 137.784853032553, 
                                                                                                                                       137.739627928243, 131.015397636158, 109.850428133857, 134.299025993379, 
                                                                                                                                       113.186634247797, 61.8508686666442, 139.094197655911, 66.0072973064438, 
                                                                                                                                       50.6238067226302, 114.483570306845, 125.222434978947, 119.448719990093, 
                                                                                                                                       139.811366923176, 117.282847760863)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                       "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -59L))
```

Comment: The sample sizes don't have to be _exactly_ the same. Do you have a source for asserting this assumption?

Comment: Yes you're right. The sample sizes don't have to be the same. But I just found the data of SLA does not conform to the normal distribution, which means that ANOVA is not applicable to it. Is there any other differential analysis method you can recommend?

Comment: See discussion below my answer on normal distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you have **one sample** with 59 observations, one outcome `SLA`, two predictors `Treatment` and `Variety`. The unequal subsample or subset sizes -- 5 of 10 and 1 of 9 -- may need some substantive explanation: was one observation missing for good reason, or was one omitted for some other reason, say as an outlier?

Statistically, your problem looks like a standard two-way ANOVA, which I would prefer to recast as a regression, but it's the same method. Quite how to do this in R is off-topic here, but presumably routine. This is what I got in Stata.

```
. regress SLA i.treatment i.variety

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        59
-------------+----------------------------------   F(6, 52)        =     20.83
       Model |  67282.7475         6  11213.7912   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  27993.8064        52   538.34243   R-squared       =    0.7062
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.6723
       Total |  95276.5538        58   1642.6992   Root MSE        =    23.202

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              SLA | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        treatment |
   Non-irrigated  |  -57.43808   6.047037    -9.50   0.000    -69.57234   -45.30381
                  |
          variety |
MG I - ES Pall..  |   21.28931   10.37634     2.05   0.045      .467653    42.11096
   MG I - Isidor  |   44.94931   10.37634     4.33   0.000     24.12766    65.77097
MG I/II - Sant..  |   42.56227   10.37634     4.10   0.000     21.74061    63.38392
 MG II - Blancas  |   34.45292   10.66597     3.23   0.002     13.05009    55.85576
  MG II - Ecudor  |   52.78751   10.37634     5.09   0.000     31.96585    73.60916
                  |
            _cons |    80.6327   7.935736    10.16   0.000     64.70848    96.55692
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. anova  SLA i.treatment i.variety

                         Number of obs =         59    R-squared     =  0.7062
                         Root MSE      =    23.2022    Adj R-squared =  0.6723

                  Source | Partial SS         df         MS        F    Prob>F
              -----------+----------------------------------------------------
                   Model |  67282.747          6   11213.791     20.83  0.0000
                         |
               treatment |  48570.564          1   48570.564     90.22  0.0000
                 variety |  18530.529          5   3706.1058      6.88  0.0001
                         |
                Residual |  27993.806         52   538.34243  
              -----------+----------------------------------------------------
                   Total |  95276.554         58   1642.6992
```

Evidently treatment is a much bigger deal than variety. In the graph the added lines show subset means. There is an indication that non-irrigated SLA is more erratic than irrigated SLA. I leave what to do or think about that an open question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It's a very detailed answer. But I just found the data of SLA does not conform to the normal distribution, which means that ANOVA is not applicable to it. Is there any other differential analysis method you can recommend?

Comment: And could you please share the name of the belowe figure? I also want to try it with STATA.

Comment: No; it's a myth that the marginal distribution of the outcome must be normal. ANOVA and regression will work fine with your data. At most you should consider so-called robust standard errors.

Comment: I used `stripplot` from SSC in Stata. The command was `stripplot SLA , over(treatment) by(Variety, note("")) refline reflinestretch(0.2)`

Comment: Thank you so so so much!